# PHP allocating minimum of 8 bytes for a string

Tags: php, memory-management

I have the following test code:

```
/* empty string */
$start_mem = memory_get_usage();
$s = '';
echo (memory_get_usage() - $start_mem); // 24

/* 1 */
$start_mem = memory_get_usage();
$s = '1';
echo (memory_get_usage() - $start_mem); // 24

/* 1234567 */
$start_mem = memory_get_usage();
$s = '1';
echo (memory_get_usage() - $start_mem); // 24

/* 12345678 */
$start_mem = memory_get_usage();
$s = '12345678';
echo (memory_get_usage() - $start_mem); // 32

/* 123456789012345 */
$start_mem = memory_get_usage();
$s = '123456789012345';
echo (memory_get_usage() - $start_mem); // 32

/* 1234567890123456 */
$start_mem = memory_get_usage();
$s = '1234567890123456';
echo (memory_get_usage() - $start_mem); // 40
```

```
Windows 7 x64
PHP 7.0.2 x86
```

Does this mean that PHP is allocating a minimum of 8 bytes of memory to a string variable regardless of its size? (1 byte denoting a string)

I believe the 24 for `$s = '';` is due to the assignment of a hash?

Is this by design or is it just how the C-code works under the hood?

Comment: [Basic reading about the structure of PHP variables](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php) and [some more reading about PHP variables](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/zvals/basic_structure.html)

Comment: I can't believe I've never come across those docs.

Comment: @MarkBaker If you would like to provide an answer in layman's terms and link the docs then I would be happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Even more useful for PHP7 - [here](https://nikic.github.io/2015/05/05/Internal-value-representation-in-PHP-7-part-1.html) and [here](https://nikic.github.io/2015/06/19/Internal-value-representation-in-PHP-7-part-2.html) by one of PHP's core developers